# Lifting a 100 gram load vertically - Best combination of motor/s, battery/ies and gearing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

A hobby question. I have a load of 100 grams. The load incorporates all the components necessary to lift itself. I want to lift the load vertically (i.e. against gravity) at a speed of, say, 1 metre per second. I intend to use a small, hobby, toy-car type micro-motor/s, probably with some type of built in reduction gearbox, so as to increase torque.

- Operating Range: 6 - 12VDC
- Torque @ Stall: 7 oz-in.@ 6VDC
- Torque @ Stall: 20 oz-in.@ 12VDC. Gear train damage can occur if stalled (locked)
- 0.118” (3mm) Diameter “D” Shaft
- No load current: 40mA (6VDC)
- No load current: 100mA (12VDC)
- Stall current: 360mA (6VDC)
- Stall current: 1600mA (12VDC)
- No load speed: 240 RPM @ 6VDC
- No load speed: 460 RPM @ 12VDC
- Gear ratio: 50:1
- Motor size: See Schematics
- Shaft size: 0.118" (3mm) Dia. x 0.393” (10mm) L
- Weight: 0.3 oz (8.5g)
- DC reversible motors

I intend to use Lithium Ion batteries (TangsFire 18350 3.7V 1500mAh Eco - friendly Li - HP Rechargeable Batteries).

I'm trying to find a workable or perhaps optimal combination of motor(s), gear reduction, and battery supply that can do the job.

The total weight of 100 grams would include the weight of the components - batteries, motor(s) etc.

The motors with a built in gearbox already attached weigh about 8.5 grams each.
The Lithium Ion batteries weigh about 15 grams each.

1. **Motors**
   Specifications a likely motors (they have the reduction gearing already built in). I will likely use three of these micro-motors working together to provide more pulling power (i.e. torque?).
   [460 RPM Micro GearmotorBlocks](https://www.servocity.com/html/460_rpm_micro_gearmotorblocks.html)
2. **Batteries**
   I plan to use 2 or 3 of these batteries: [TangsFire 18350 3.7V 1500mAh Eco - friendly Li - HP Rechargeable Battery -  YELLOW 10](http://www.gearbest.com/batteries/pp_91848.html)

Questions:

1. **Doable at all?** Will it pull a 100 gram load vertically upwards?
   The device will be attached to a string and it will hang down from a fixed point above the device. A bit like a mini-elevator.
2. **If it is doable**, what would be the **maximum speed** that it could travel at in an upwards direction?

Comment: Reading through the post it is difficult state if it is doable. It is best  you try and work out the issues as you go along. Anything can be achieve if you try.

Comment: @Phil it would be helpful to potential answerers to convert to a common set of units. In particular the motor is specified in oz/in and your load is in grams and speed is in m/s. Also, input power to a DC motor is voltage * current. Output power will be "input - losses" or "input * %losses". Totally guessing here, but losses may be in the 30%-70% range, and will partly depend on gearing. It'd be helpful to state input power and a guess of output power you expect. Also need to know how fast you want your load to accelerate. Low acceleration means a long time to reach 1 m/s.